# Xcode and Logging out in IOS

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6

For a business app on iphone/ipad, wanted to add login and logout. Everytime, I use the app and navigate to a set of workflow and suddently hit "Home" (the center button at bottom of iphone) in iphone/ipad and go to some other application and then return after an hour, I am at same place where i left.

I want to have login and the design in my mind is when I hit the first screen ViewDidLoad, check for a user-id variable value, if it empty, call a modal form, authenticate and pass the value and allow the user to navigate the menu. Obviously webservices will be authenticated again (hopefully, right now all hardcoded) to pass info security

Questions

1. Is there something like logout ?
2. After authentication, in instaces where user presses home to do some other navigation like check email or call and do something else, Is there an event that i can trigger and logout ?
3. Is there something like idle session timeout in ios app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [App States](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) guide may provide some help.

`applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `applicationWillResignActive:` will likely be of particular interest.

Comment: The document is great. Stackoverflow has helped me a great deal to learn and build apps :)